# Trying to send email based on checkbox selection

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, gmail

I am trying to send emails automatically if the checkboxes in Column H are checked. I barely know enough about code to get in trouble. The code I have has been Frankensteined together, so I know I'm missing something but I'm too new at this to understand what. If I run the code as-is, an email is sent if there is an email address listed in Column G, but it is sent regardless of if Column H is checked or not. I don't want an email sent if the checkbox is not checked. I've searched through the forums and have tried to piece together a solution that works for me but I just keep hitting a wall. I know the problem lies with identifying the checkbox and that's where I'm getting lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var EMAIL_SENT = "EMAIL_SENT";

function send1stnotice() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3;  // First row of data to process
  var numRows = sheet.getLastRow()-1   // Number of rows to process
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, 1000)
  // Fetch values for each row in the Range.
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var checkbox1 =row[7];
    var emailAddress = row[6];
    if (emailAddress.match('@') == null){
        continue;
    };  // First column
    var subject = "test subject";     
    var message = "test message";    
    var emailSent = row[8];     

    if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT &&  checkbox1!= 'FALSE') {  // Prevents sending duplicates

      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue(EMAIL_SENT);
      // Make sure the cell is updated right away in case the script is interrupted
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your condition to this:

```
if (emailSent != EMAIL_SENT && checkbox1 == true)
```

The value of a checkbox is a [boolean](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Boolean), not the string "TRUE" or "FALSE". You were checking if it equals "TRUE", but it doesn't. Because you're using [`getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues), Apps Script interprets the actual value of the data you see in the spreadsheet.

> The values may be of type Number, Boolean, Date, or String, depending
>   on the value of the cell.

If you wanted to compare against the data *exactly* as it appears in the spreadsheet, you could use [`getDisplayValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getdisplayvalues), although I personally rarely find need for this. Anyway, if you used `getDisplayValues()`, then the checkbox would return either "TRUE" or "FALSE" strings in all caps.

You can check this using [`Logger.log()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger#logdata) to see the value of checkbox1.

```
// Try with getValues()
var data = dataRange.getValues();
var checkbox1 =data[i][7];
Logger.log(typeof checkbox1); // boolean
Logger.log(checkbox1); // Returns either true or false

// Try again, but with getDisplayValues()
var data = dataRange.getDisplayValues();
var checkbox1 =data[i][7];
Logger.log(typeof checkbox1); // string
Logger.log(checkbox1); // Returns either "TRUE" or "FALSE"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function send1stnotice() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var startRow = 3;
  var dataRange = sheet.getRange(startRow, 1, sheet.getLastRow()-2,sheet.getLastColumn());
  var data = dataRange.getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var row = data[i];
    var checkbox1 =row[7];
    var emailAddress = row[6];
    var subject = "test subject";     
    var message = "test message";    
    var emailSent = sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).getValue();     
    if (emailSent != "EMAIL_SENT" &&  checkbox1=="TRUE") { 
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
      sheet.getRange(startRow + i, 9).setValue("EMAIL_SENT");
      SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    }
  }
}
```