# How to automatically send an email if checkbox gets checked

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'd like an email to be sent whenever a checkbox is checked in a google sheet. Does anyone have good code I can use?

Example: like when column F check box have been checked it will auto send an email like attached picture.

Sorry as i totally noob about scripts and don't no where to start.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vMxxf.png)

Comment: Hi Boon! Welcome to SO. This really does not look good if you ask for code like this, rather post what you have tried so far or maybe research a bit and then post where you stuck, then people are here to help you.

Comment: also this might be a possible duplicate of your question [Trying to send email based on checkbox selection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58983247/trying-to-send-email-based-on-checkbox-selection)

Comment: Hello, Sorry as i totally noob about scripts and don't no where to start. i did re-attached the picture with feature that i need. Hope anyone can help me and really appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

#### Send Email When Check Box in A1 Is Checked

```
function sendEmailWhenCheckBoxIsChecked(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == 'Send Emails' && e.range.columnStart==1 && e.range.rowStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    e.range.setValue('FALSE');
    GmailApp.sendEmail("your email addres","The subject","The message");
  }
}
```

- Create installable trigger

  function createTriger() {
  if(ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().filter(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == 'sendEmailWhenCheckBoxIsChecked').length ==0) {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('sendEmailWhenCheckBoxIsChecked').forSpreadsheet(ss.getActive()).onEdit().create();
  }
  }

[Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)

Comment: Hi Cooper, Thanks for your script and seeking your help to see it there script can help as per attached photo request.

Answer (score 0):

This runs with an installable trigger. If you don't want an installable trigger, you can change the function `sendEmailWhenBoxIsChecked()` to `onEdit()`, delete the `onOpen()` function and get rid of `wholeSheet` variable.

Let me know if you have any questions.

```
const wholeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
let sheetName = "name of your sheet";
let activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);

function sendEmailWhenBoxIsChecked() {
  let columnIndexOfCheckbox = 6; //column index of where your checkbox is located
  let rowIndexOfCheckbox = 2; //column index of where your checkbox starts
  let activeCellOfActiveSheet = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
  if (
    activeCellOfActiveSheet.getColumn() === columnIndexOfCheckbox
    && activeCellOfActiveSheet.getRowIndex() >= rowIndexOfCheckbox
    && !activeCellOfActiveSheet.isBlank()
  ) {
    let checkbox = activeSheet.getActiveCell();
    if (checkbox.isChecked()) {
      GmailApp.sendEmail("recipient email", "Email header", "Email content or body");
    }

  }

}

function onOpen() {
  let createTrigger = true;
  ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().forEach(trigger => {
    if (trigger.getEventType() === ScriptApp.EventType.ON_EDIT && sendEmailWhenBoxIsChecked.name === trigger.getHandlerFunction()) createTrigger = false;
  });
  if (createTrigger) {
    ScriptApp.newTrigger(sendEmailWhenBoxIsChecked.name)
      .forSpreadsheet(wholeSheet)
      .onEdit()
      .create();
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello Emmanuel Mireku, Thanks for the code and after I try the script it only can auto email when the checkbox was checked on row 2..then when row ro3 check box is checked it happen nothing.